# How to pre-fill form with ngModel in Angular

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms, ngmodel

When I open the form I want some fields to be pre-filled with values. That's why I use `[checked]="userFilter[u.id]"` below.

However, as soon I as include the `ngModel` directive into the element, the form does not show the values pre-filled.

For example

```
<!-- works and checks/unchecks the box according to userFilter[u.id] when first opening the form -->
<input type="checkbox" id="{{u.id}}" name="{{u.name}}" [checked]="userFilter[u.id]">


<!-- does not check or uncheck the box according to userFilter[u.id] when first opening the form -->
<input type="checkbox" id="{{u.id}}" name="{{u.name}}" ngModel [checked]="userFilter[u.id]">
```

I want to use ngModel because when I submit the form I want to access all fields and values as follows:

```
onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
   console.log('form values', f.value); 
}
```

which works fine as well, but I need to open the form with some values already defined

thanks

Comment: Try `[ngModel]="userFilter[u.id]"`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan thanks man! Don't know why I was stuck trying with `[checked]` 

Switching to `[ngModel]` worked. You may want to post the answer to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set the initial state of the checkbox, use one-way data binding with `[ngModel]`:

```
[ngModel]="userFilter[u.id]"
```